# How to track a packet in order to list the source pod ip and the destination pod ip

Tags: networking, kubernetes

How can I obtain the final destination pod ip to which a request is routed in a Kubernetes network with the use of service? Is it possible to hook with netfilter to obtain client pod ip and server pod ip to which the packet will be routed.
Will Kube proxy list all the incoming requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-o jsonpath` to get information you need from the service and endpoints objects.

To get pod's IP which service is pointing to:

```
kubectl get endpoints <service_name> -o jsonpath='{.subsets[].addresses[].ip}'
```

To get service IP:

```
kubectl get service <service_name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.clusterIP}'
```

Comment: If there are replica pods how can you find which pod was selected for a given request.

Comment: It's randomly selected.